# How to include user input in the html string of a some parent DOM element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-history, html-input

I want to store the content of a div container in windows history, by running the following line:

```
window.history.pushState($('#myDivId').html(), "title", 'some url');
```

I would later use this info when user presses the back button.

---

### Problem:

User has a form to fill, with one input. User types his name (say John) and clicks on submit. The `onSubmit` function is triggered and here I get the html content of parent div and store it in history object. The problem is, user input (John) in this example, is not captured.

The following screenshot shows the output of my script below:

[image]

### Code Snippet

```js
function onSubmit() {
   var str = $('#myDivId').html();
   alert("this goes to windows history: " + str);
   // window.history.pushState($('#myDivId').html(), "title", 'some url');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form onsubmit="onSubmit()">
   <div id="myDivId">
      First name: <input id="firstNameId" type="text" name="FirstName" value=""><br>
      <input type="submit" value="submit">
   </div>
</form>
```

How can include user input in the `str` before pushing it in the history?

### Update:

This is a simplified example, in the real scenario I have several input fields in the container. So I am looking for a way to capture all the input values through the container.

Comment: `$('#myDivId').html()` will give the entire HTML content of the div and not the value of input box

Comment: Thanks, I have added an update to the question. So the Div contains server linput values and I was hoping to find an easy way to capture all this input through the part div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `value` attribute represents the *default* value of the field, not the current value.

There is no HTML attribute which reflects that.

If you want to store it, then you need to store it explicitly.

I'd approach this by using [`serializeArray()`](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) (and converting it to JSON to store in the history), and then looping over it to restore the data to the form.

Answer (score 1):

Here I'm using a [`delegate event`](https://api.jquery.com/delegate/) to set `value` property as `value` attribute

```js
function onSubmit() {
   var str = $('#myDivId').html();
   alert("this goes to windows history: " + str);
   // window.history.pushState($('#myDivId').html(), "title", 'some url');
}

$(document).on('input', '.attr-input', function() {
  $(this).attr('value', this.value)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form onsubmit="onSubmit()">
   <div id="myDivId">
      First name: <input id="firstNameId" class="attr-input" type="text" name="FirstName" value=""><br>
      <input type="submit" value="submit">
   </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not clear what you are asking. I have provided a solution as per my understanding.

```js
function onSubmit() {
  $("#firstNameId").attr('value', $("#firstNameId").val())
   var str = $('#myDivId').html();
   alert("this goes to windows history: " + str);
   // window.history.pushState($('#myDivId').html(), "title", 'some url');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form onsubmit="onSubmit()">
   <div id="myDivId">
      First name: <input id="firstNameId" type="text" name="FirstName" value=""><br>
      <input type="submit" value="submit">
   </div>
</form>
```